# Redirect an output to a file from command piping grep

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I am running this:

`cat  /dev/urandom|hexdump| grep -i "ffff f" > random`

and I get nothing in file `random`, it remains zero length after the command is interrupted.

**How to make it writing output to a file?**

I need to write a result to a file, which should contains output data like this:

`021bc40 7724 d4f5 59ec bcbb ffff fd26 ab3c 9b7c`

`03a9100 b3a5 8601 fa33 ffff f23c 4326 2e7f 0c8a`

`0449810 e459 d5af 4e11 ffff fc55 8660 9efb 3c9b`

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `--line-buffered` option for `grep` (and also get rid of the useless `cat`):

```
hexdump /dev/urandom | grep --line-buffered -i "ffff f" > random
```

This way the output is not buffered but every line put into `random` immediately. I would also recommend to use `tee` in your pipe to see how many lines have been produced:

```
hexdump /dev/urandom | grep --line-buffered -i "ffff f" | tee random
```

Answer (score 3):

Your file is empty because the process is interrupted before the file is written to disk. That is how redirection works. As a workaround, try this:

```
script -c 'cat /dev/urandom|hexdump|grep -i "ffff f"' -f random
```

This will basically write all screen output to the file.

Comment: It involved one more command, but delivered. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`cat /dev/urandom|hexdump` or `hexdump /dev/urandom` writes continuously to the stdout and if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> nothing will be executed after this. But you can limit the output with `head`

```
hexdump /dev/urandom | head -n1000000 | grep "ffff f" > random
```

this will `grep` in the first 1000000 lines of the output and writes the result to a file.

Comment: Involved one more command, but gave a good result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write the output of `cat /dev/urandom | hexdump` to a file before you execute it the next time. The script below should accomplish what you are trying:

```
cat /dev/urandom | hexdump |
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >> random;
  done
```

`IFS` is used to split the output into lines here.

---

[(Source)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55624/limit-stdout-from-a-continuously-running-process)

Comment: `grep "ffff f"` missed